# Inline Interactive Plots with Julia in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, julia

when I use

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get interactive plots, i.e. I can also zoom into the figure.

For julia this command does not seem to exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for (not inlined) but you can get interactivity by using `pygui(true)`

Answer (score 5):

You can get interactive plots by using Plotly, either directly with [Plotly.jl](https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.jl) or through  its [Plots](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/examples/plotlyjs/) backend.

Answer (score 2):

Today I am thinking about how to enlarge the plot window interactively without referring to `python` or `plotly` or something else in Jupiter notebook. And I find a good solution. It is to use the package `Interact`. A simple example is as follows. You can get an interactive plot in 3 lines.

```
  import Pkg; Pkg.add("Interact")
  using LinearAlgebra, Plots, Interact

  @manipulate for n in 10:100, w in 200:1000, h in 200:1000
    plot(randn(n),randn(n),seriestype=:scatter,label="n=$(n)",size = (w, h))
  end
```

The result looks like this
[image]