# Plotly + Julia + Latex

Tags: latex, julia, plotly, plots.jl

I would like to use latex with the Plotly backend. Look in this example: Even the x-axis and y-axis log scales are not formatted properly! Do you know how to do that?

Best,

v.

```
using Plots, LaTeXStrings
plotlyjs()
x =  10 .^ LinRange(-5,5,10)

plot(x, 1 ./ x, yaxis=:log, xaxis=:log, m = 2, xlabel="x", label="1/x",ylabel="f(x)")
plot!(x, 10 ./ x, m=2,label="10/x")
plot!(x, 1 ./ (x.^2), m=2, label=L"f(x)=$1/x^2$")
savefig("./test.png")
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work with the `gr()` backend, so I expect LaTeXString is not supported by the `plotlyjs()` backend.

[image]

Comment: Yea, I think this is the reason. Hope there is a solution for this, though.